# Will 74HC595 as LED sink damage LED when pin goes high?

Tags: led, current, shift-register

If used as a LED sink, what happens if a 74HC595 pin goes high?  Might the LED blow?

I expect that when a pin is low, current will sink and the LED will light.

What about the opposite condition?  When a the pin goes high, might there be risk of blowing LED's due to reverse flow?  Why or why not?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1SPlu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer lies in the reverse voltage rating of the LED chosen. Common through-hole LEDs typically are rated at 5 Volts reverse, some LEDs higher. This means that for up to 5 Volts applied in reverse bias, the LED will behave as a regular diode, blocking current flow. Beyond this voltage, reverse breakdown might occur, potentially destroying the LED if the voltage is high enough.

In the schematic shown, the PWM signal is 0 to 5 Volts. Thus, even when the PWM signal is low, and the latch output is high, the maximum reverse voltage the LED is exposed to is less than 5 Volts. So the LEDs will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Being a *diode*, your LEDs will not suffer any damage, provided that the voltage being applied is below is breakdown voltage. +5V is generally safe for diodes commonly used.

Comment: Gah, beat me to it!

Comment: +5V will make most LEDs DED (Dark Emitting Diodes).

Answer (score 3):

Almost all LEDs are **rated** for at least 5V reverse voltage.

In actual practice, I've never seen one that broke down even at 12V.

(Pulsed) reverse bias is a normal operational condition for multiplexed LED displays.